# Oracle Import error Illegal lob length marker 57799

Tags: oracle, import

I am trying to perform an import with the following command: 
**imp.exe username/password@db file:C:\dump.dmp rows=y grants=n indexes=n ignore=y full=y log=C:\import.lst**
but once the import reaches a certain table it gives me the following error:
*Illegal lob length marker 57799
bytesread = 00000000000
Table = table_name
IMP-00098: INTERNAL ERROR: impgst2^C*

Any idea what im doing wrong here ? i really appreciate the help

thanks

Comment: Your dump file might be corrupt. It is a binary file.

Comment: agree with @ShriramM. try the import with show=y and see what the output is